# Keep only unmatched records when joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have 2 access tables that contain partially similar data, one being more enriched than the other.
The idea here is to join the two tables by the fields **id** and **num** and to get from the table T2 the num that are not in the table T1

T1:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |
| 3 | 51 |
| 7 | 23 |

T2:

| id | num | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | done |
| 1 | 79 | done |
| 1 | 39 | done |
| 3 | 51 | done |
| 7 | 23 | done |

Expected result:

| id | num | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 79 | done |
| 1 | 39 | done |

Under access I read on internet that there is no MINUS operator like under MySQL, so I tried with EXCEPT but the query takes a long time (stopped after 10min)

So I tried this:

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 ON (T1.id =T2.id) 
WHERE T1.num IS NULL AND ( (T2.status LIKE 'done') );
```

The problem now is, I don't have all the records that are in T2 but not in T1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RIGHT JOIN. And I recommend to do not use "LIKE" in this case because this is slow. You can just use the = operator. So your query will be:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.num, t2.status 
FROM t1 
RIGHT JOIN t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.num = t2.num
WHERE t1.num IS NULL
AND t2.status = 'done';
```

In case all column names you want to join are identic in both tables, you can join more simple:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.num, t2.status 
FROM t1 
RIGHT JOIN t2 
USING (id,num)
WHERE t1.num IS NULL
AND t2.status = 'done';
```

I don't like this, but it's shorter. At the end, your concrete query depends on your personal "taste".

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of variants.

```sql
SELECT t2.*
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 USING (id, num)
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
  AND t2.status = 'done'
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM t1
                   WHERE (t1.id, t1.num) = (t2.id, t2.num) )
  AND status = 'done'
```

There are more variants...

What of these (or maybe some another) variants is the most effective? this depends on the tables definitions and data statistic.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the second variant dosn't work for me as the data volume is too big

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a condition on the join:

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM      T2 
LEFT JOIN T1 
       ON T1.id  = T2.id
      AND T1.num = T2.num
WHERE T1.num IS NULL 
  AND T2.status LIKE 'done';
```

Check it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73XzTiZT9zHH4Ffgsc1s1u/0).